# Powershell script throwing System.Management.Automation.PSMethod error on SetAccessRule

Tags: powershell, exception, methods

I'm getting this error in my script when I use AddAccessRule:

Exception setting "AddAccessRule": "Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod"."

I have researched lots of similar scripts, but I'm having no luck searching on this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Script below:

```
'''

$folders = get-childitem -path "C:\Users\spewingadmin\Documents\reports_bak2\" -Recurse

Foreach($folder in $folders){
$foldacl = get-acl -Path $folder.FullName
$InheritanceFlag = $foldacl.Access.InheritanceFlags
$PropagationFlag = $foldacl.Access.PropagationFlags
$objType = $foldacl.Access.AccessControlType
$Permissions = $foldacl.Access.FileSystemRights

For ($x=0;$x -lt $foldacl.Access.Count;$x++){
    $user = $foldacl.Access.IdentityReference[$x]
    $domainresult = $user.Value.substring(0,($user.Value.indexof("\")))

    If(($domainresult -eq "WORKGROUP")) {
        $username = $user.Value.substring((($user.Value.indexof("\")) + 1),($user.Value.length - $user.Value.indexof("\") - 1))
        $DomainUser = "NEWWORKGROUP\" + $username
        $NewPerms = ($domainuser,$Permissions,$InheritanceFlag,$PropagationFlag,$objType)
        $Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $NewPerms
        $Ar
        $foldacl.SetAccessRule=($Ar)
        
    }
}
##Set-acl -Path $folder.FullName -AclObject $foldacl
##$foldacl
}
```

'''

Comment: The intention of the script is to copy the user rights and recreate them for a new domain that the files have been copied to.

Comment: is the equals sign in this just a typo? The parentheses make me think its supposed to be a method call?  $foldacl.SetAccessRule=($Ar)   If so i think it might explain your error

Comment: Thanks all, it was the equals sign. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can return a string no problem, but it is quite finicky setting it up. It is hard to tell what’s happening without seeing the parameters, script, variables, etc.

Is the powershell script itself setup to output a string? Double check that the names are correct in the PowerShellVariables pop-up window and that the direction is set to `out` and that the type is `string` and you are setting the value to the correct UiPath variable

Comment: Here are the values that are in $Ar:                                                          
FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NEWWORKGROUP\spewingadmin
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

Comment: The problem turned out to be a mere _typo_: an extraneous `=` in the `.SetAccessRule()` method call. In light of that, your answer is a bit of distraction. Can I suggest you either amend or delete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

[diopside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8032828/diopside) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

You have an **extraneous `=`** in the following attempt at a method call, and **removing it fixed your problem**, as you've confirmed:

```sh
# Note the extraneous "="
$foldacl.SetAccessRule=($Ar)  # !! WRONG
```

should be:

```sh
# OK - syntactically correct method call.
$foldacl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
```

Therefore, your question qualifies for closure based on the standard reason "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

However, given the somewhat **obscure nature of the error message** - `Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod".` - perhaps an **explanation** is helpful:

- PowerShell allows you to **obtain a .NET method's *signature (overloads)*, by simply omitting the `(...)`**, which returns one or more [`System.Management.Automation.PSMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSMethod) instances:

```sh
PS> 'foo'.ToString # Note: *No* () to actually *call* the .ToString() method.

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string ToString()
string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
```

- Trying to *assign* to such a method-signature object (group) - which doesn't make any sense - then results in the aforementioned error message:

```sh
PS> 'foo'.ToString = 'whatever' # !! Predictably fails.

[...] Exception setting "ToString": "Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object [...]"
```